# Popup ability lost after Form action is taken

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-mobile, webmatrix

On a web page, I have some "Ignore this person" type of buttons.  I'm attempting to use a pop up confirmation form which opens after a user clicks one of these buttons.  I have 1 pop up confirmation form per "potential ignoree".  These popups work as intended the first time, but once a popup form's action is carried out, I cannot get another such form to open/display by a subsequent button click.  Here is my pop up form html and razor code:

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="showIgnoreDialog@(i)" data-theme="a" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
      <form action="~/DisplayNames?ind=@passedIndex&sN=@whoToIgnore&tId=-2" id ="ignoreFormId" method="get"> 
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
          <h1 id="popupHeader">Ignore them</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
      @{
       // make sure the name fits in box below
       if(whoToIgnore.Length > 25)
       {
         whoToIgnore30 = whoToIgnore.Substring(0, 25);
         whoToIgnore = whoToIgnore30 + "...";
       }
       }
          <h3 id="popupInnerHeader" class="ui-title">Ignore @whoToIgnore?</h3>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
          <button type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="c">Ignore</button>
        </div>  
      </form>
```

Below this code on the cshtml page I have the following Jquery/Javascript:

```
function showIgnoreForm(i)
{
  // var z = confirm("Works after submission...");
  $("#showIgnoreDialog"+ i).popup('open');
}
```

I have tried to stick the functions inside a "document ready function" like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{ 
  // I've had no success placing showIgnoreForm(i) in here
}
```

I have also tried using document.getElementById as well to no avail.  I know the ignore button itself still works after the Form action is taken, because the "confirm" Javascript dialog fires after a submission.  Basically, I imagine I need to know how to get the $("#showIgnoreDialog"+ i)... line to work after my Form's action has been completed.

Comment: can you confirm that there are no java script errors after the first pop-up?

Comment: Hey Adam, I didn't even know I could check for errors in JS - first website here - thanks.  I used try/catch at the javascript call, and I see no error reported, for either the first popup, or the second attempted popup.

Comment: Perhaps related - when I place the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Kvj8/ in my page, the div dialog (that is supposed to be hidden at the start) is open.  Meaning this: autoOpen: false isn't working on my page.

Comment: Are you using JQ UI or JQM? I would use one or the other, not both if possible. In JQM, use Popup or make a dialog from a second page.

Comment: Twisty - I have tried both JQM (my real Popup code posted above), and JQ UI (the fiddle code linked above), but I would be happy with either one.  I don't want to blend the two.  When I simply cut and paste example code from online, it doesn't work on my page.  I'm wondering if there is a correct sequence to include jquery scripts in, it would seem that code working online should work in my environment, unless my environment is wacked.  I'm looking into this yet.

Comment: After several wacks at this over the past few weeks, and seeing a few other unanswered posts with the same issue, I'm moving on and going with a different method to confirm with my users.  I'll use a sliding div with confirm buttons - it looks decent.  Thanks for the help guys.